# Running a Powershell command in the Windows CMD and getting colour output

Tags: windows, command-line, powershell, colors

When I run this command in Powershell it outputs with colour.

```
(curl wttr.in -UserAgent curl).Content
```

However when I run the same command in the Windows CMD, I get the same output but with no colour.

```
powershell (curl wttr.in -UserAgent curl).Content
```

---

**How do I run a Powershell command in the Windows CMD and get the output *in colour* as it would display in Powershell?**

---

[image: demo]

Comment: My first question would be why are you regressing to cmd? Why not just stay in Powershell. Next I would point out that this cannot be done in a standard cmd.exe console.

Comment: My preference is to use the standard Windows CMD. Can you provide an explanation as to why it is not possible?

Comment: Because the standard cmd.exe does not provide hooks for programatically changing the color of the output. Actually that is not entirely true. Starting with Win 10, cmd.exe does support standard ANSI escape sequences. So I suppose that you could write a batch file that takes the output of the powershell command, reparses it it then changes the colors for output. Or alternatively you could use the newer technology.

Comment: Appreciate the explanation. Can you provide any more clarity on what would be required in terms of reparsing the Powershell output (especially as Win10 now supports standard ANSI escape sequences)? Even one example just to get me going.

Comment: probably some problem with your cmd settings, because [it works without problem in my place](https://imgur.com/a/Q2j36pT). Anyway, very interesting link

Comment: On github there is a script [Get-ConsoleAsHtml.ps1](https://gist.github.com/lazywinadmin/101ecf6530b794e3b7a7) which scans the console buffer and converts to html detecting color changes. You could take that as a base but I'm with EBGreen - IMO not worth the effort.

Comment: See if this gets you started https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2048509/how-to-echo-with-different-colors-in-the-windows-command-line

Comment: @phuclv thanks for the heads up - updated [AnsIcon](https://github.com/adoxa/ansicon) and it does indeed work with colours without the need for reparsing. All because you tried my example yourself.